# best way to handle stripe subscription upgrade and downgrade

Tags: stripe-payments

I have read in the documenation that the stripe has only one api for subscription update for both upgrade and downgrade.

I have 2 products to which user subscribe, `Basic` and `Plus`, both are paid.When I upgrade form Basic to Plus, I do the following:

- Subscribe the user to another product.
- Delete the previous product from the subscription.

It means at some point user is subscribed to two products in one subscription. What is the best way to handle it?

Now if user downgrades, my buisness logic is to do not cancel the current subscription immidietly. For example, if user wants to go from Plus to Basic. The Basic will start once Plus has finished.
Heres how I am handling it currently:

- Cancel the current subscription with property `cancel_at_period_end: true`
- Start the next subscirption with a `trial period`, so user is charged once current subscription is ended

Now this whole senerio is very strange for me. what is the best way to handle my upgrade/downgrade with the update api of stripe. I am using `NodeJs`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding your use case correctly - it sounds like you want to update a subscription but not switch from Plus -> Basic (and vice versa) until the end of the billing cycle?

Comment: @karbi, when someone downgrades I dont want to switch untill the end of the billing cycle. but when someone updates, i would like to happen instently.

Comment: In our case, we decided to write our own service. This is a blog post about it - https://blog.widefix.com/stripe-plan-change-proration-service/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need for the customer to have two separate Subscriptions - you can manage this with a single Subscription that is updated in different ways depending on whether it's an upgrade or a downgrade.

**Downgrade**
Create a Subscription Schedule for the Subscription, which will allow you to schedules changes for a Subscription in the future. Schedules can get very complicated, so I'd highly suggest reading through all of Stripe's [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules) and glancing through the Schedules [API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules). The general flow for how you'd change the price of a Subscription at the end of the current billing cycle goes like this:

1. Generate a Subscription Schedule from an existing Subscription (see [example](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription))
2. Take the Subscription Schedule and [update it](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules#updating) to add an additional phase (which is passed into `phases`). You'll pass in two phases during the update request - The first phase should be the existing current phase on the Subscription Schedule, and the second phase should represent the subscription once it's been downgraded by setting `phases[1][iterations]: 1`, `phases[1][items][0][price]`, and `phases[1][items][0][quantity]`.

**Upgrade** Stripe's documentation has great example of how to do this already [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#changing). To summarize it quickly, you'll want to retrieve the Subscription, grab the [Subscription Item ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-items-data-id) for the item you want to change, and make an [update](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) request by setting `items[0].id` with the ID you retrieved and `items[0].price` with the new price. Depending on whether or not you want prorations, you would also set `proration_behavior`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. What if while upgrade, I have Schedules?

Comment: It depends on the behavior you want - if you want to upgrade a user but they already have a schedule, you could just release the schedule (https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/release) to cancel the future downgrade.

Comment: This is much more complicated than it should be from stripe side. Downgrade supposed to be easy

Answer (score 1):

I am also struggling with the upgrading/downgrading of the stripe subscription. Currently, I am okay with the upgrading, cause I just update the subscription there and prorate on the next invoice. However, I am not sure why I am not able to downgrade successfully with the steps that @karbi provided. My code is as follows:

```js
//* 2. Schedule the current subscription
let schedule = await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.create({ from_subscription: latestActiveSubscription.id })
const currPhase = schedule.phases[0]

//* 3. Update the schedule by adding second phase to downgrade to the new plan
schedule = await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.update(
    schedule.id,
    {
        phases: [
            currPhase,
            {
                items: [{ price: newSubscriptionPlan.stripePlanId, quantity: 1 }],
                proration_behavior: 'none',
                iterations: 1
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

However, this gave me an error where the `phase[0][collection_method]` is missing:

```
You passed an empty string for 'phases[0][collection_method]'...
```

I saw the response from the schedule creating from the current subscription and saw that in the `phases[0]` the `collection_method = null`, but in the schedule itself, it was the correct one - `charge_automatically`. Therefore, I decided to assign it to the phase before updating like `currPhase.collection_method = schedule.collection_method`. Sadly, there was no success, because another error occurred:

```js
If passing an array with explicit keys (e.g. 'foo[0]=a&foo[1]=b') instead of as an array (e.g. 'foo[]=a&foo[]=b'), the keys must be numeric and sequential starting from 0. You passed the keys '1', we expected to have a key with the value '0'.
```

Then, I got back to the documentation to check what are the update options and I updated the schedule as follows:

```js
//* 3. Update the schedule by adding second phase to downgrade to the new plan
schedule = await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.update(
    schedule.id,
    {
        phases: [
            // currPhase,
            {
                items: [{ price: currPhase.items[0].price, quantity: 1 }],
                start_date: currPhase.start_date,
                end_date: currPhase.end_date,
                proration_behavior: 'none'
            },
            {
                items: [{ price: newSubscriptionPlan.stripePlanId, quantity: 1 }],
                proration_behavior: 'none',
                iterations: 1
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Now, it looks like it works, but not sure if that is the correct way to do so. I will verify tomorrow if the schedule will automatically change the subscription plan.

**UPDATE:**

Little bit late update, but the above code works like a charm.